# how to get the result from recursive promises in a redux action

Tags: reactjs, redux, promise, aws-sdk

I've searched the net, and I can't find out a solution. My final goal is to pull all the data from a dynamodb table. The problem is when a table is bigger than 1MB, in the response I'll get one chunk of data and a `LastEvaluatedKey` parameter (which provides the index I can use in the next call to get the next chunk). The `scan` operation is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#scan-property) if needed.

I'm using reactjs, redux and redux-thunk in my app.

I have used promises moderately in the single or chained formats, but this one is more challenging that I could resolve so far. What puzzles me is the fact that the new calls can not be made without receiving the previous response, so the calls can not be done simultaneously in my opinion. In another hand since the `scan` operation is a promise (as far as I understand)  if I try to return a promise from my own method the action does not receive the results.

I'm very confused and I really like to understand how I can get this to work.

**action:**

```
function getDynamodbTableRecords(tableName) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(request());

        var recordsSet = [];
        var data = myAwsService.getTableRecords(tableName, null) || {Items:[]};
        if (data.Items.length > 0){
            data.Items.map(record => {
                recordsSet.push(record);
            });

            dispatch(success(recordsSet));
        } else {
            dispatch(failure("No Records Found!"));
        }
    };

    function request() { return { type: DATA_LOADING, selectedTable: tableName } }
    function success(tableRecords) { return { type: DATA_LOAD_SUCCESS, tableRecords } }
    function failure(error) { return { type: DATA_LOAD_FAILED, errors: error } }
}
```

**myAwsService:**

```
function getTableRecords(tableName, lastEvaluatedKey = null) {
    getRecordsBatch(tableName, lastEvaluatedKey)
    .then(
        data => {
            if (data.LastEvaluatedKey) {
                return getTableRecords(tableName, data.LastEvaluatedKey)
                .then(
                    nextData => {
                        data.Items = data.Items.concat(nextData.Items);
                    }
                )
            }

            return data;
        }
    )
}

function getRecordsBatch(tableName, lastEvaluatedKey = null) {
    var awsDynamodb = new DynamoDB();

    let params = { TableName: tableName };
    if (lastEvaluatedKey) {
        params['ExclusiveStartKey'] = lastEvaluatedKey;
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        awsDynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }

            return resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if your recursive promise is working but I'd do it like this:

```
function getTableRecords(
  tableName,
  lastEvaluatedKey = null,
  result = { Items: [] }
) {
  return getRecordsBatch(tableName, lastEvaluatedKey).then(
    data => {
      if (data.LastEvaluatedKey) {
        return getTableRecords(
          tableName,
          data.LastEvaluatedKey,
          {
            ...data,
            Items: result.Items.concat(data.Items),
          }
        );
      }

      return {
        ...data,
        Items: result.Items.concat(data.Items),
      };
    }
  );
}
```

The action should also dispatch the data.Items and not the promise that getTabelRecords returns and you probably want to dispatch failure action if something goes wrong:

```
function getDynamodbTableRecords(tableName) {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(request());

    //you probably want the data, not a promise of data
    try {
      var data = await myAwsService.getTableRecords(
        tableName,
        null
      );
      if (data.Items.length > 0) {
        //no reason to have the temporary recordSet variable
        dispatch(success(data.Items.map(record => record)));
      } else {
        dispatch(failure('No Records Found!'));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(failure(e.message));
    }
  };

  function request() {
    return { type: DATA_LOADING, selectedTable: tableName };
  }
  function success(tableRecords) {
    return { type: DATA_LOAD_SUCCESS, tableRecords };
  }
  function failure(error) {
    return { type: DATA_LOAD_FAILED, errors: error };
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm so sorry for the delay. I'm trying to fix an error that is showing up in console. `Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined` happening at the async location. I'll see if I can fix that up soon and see if the code works

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the huge delay here. It finally worked! Thank you :)